# DBIx::Class Update one table from another

Tags: mysql, dbix-class

I have a SQL query which works fine directly in MySQL, but I'm struggling to convert it to use via DBIx::Class, I've simplified the query here

```
UPDATE table1, table2
    SET table1.field1 = SOMEFUNC( table1.field4 / table2.field2 )
    WHERE table1.id = table2.id
        AND table1.field3 = table2.field3
        AND table2.field2 IS NOT NULL
        AND table2.field2 > 0;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have the original code anymore as I had to implement it a different way (i.e. do resultset->search and then update each row individually), but I had try to implement it doing a search on the join chained to an update, but MySQL complains that I'm trying to update a field in the where clause.

Answer (score 2):

In similar cases I usually perform a search on the related table. In your case you have two result sources: **table1** and **table2**. **table1** has a relationship to the table **table2** (most probably) named *table2*. So now you perform a search in the **table2** using this relationship *table2*.

```
my $resultset = $schema->resultset('table1')->search_rs(
   {
      me.field3 => table2.field3,
      table2.field2 => {'!=', '' },
      table2.field2 > 0
   },
   {
      'join' => 'table2',
      'select' => ['me.field1', 'me.field4', 'table2.field2', 'me.field4' / 'table2.field2' ],
      'as' => ['field1','field4', 'field2', 'division_result']
   }
);

while ( my $this_res_row = $resultset->next ) {
   ## Presuming somefunc is a perl subroutine
   $this_res_row->update( { field1 => somefunc( $this_res_row->get_column('division_result') ) } );
}
```

Maybe this is the solution you have come up with, I think it is not possible to do what you want in a single dbic update() statement. Unfortunately, each update() statement will hit your database separately.

By the way, I don't think it is a good idea ta make a second union on the same tables via **field3**, you have it already done via **id** fields. Why would you need another one?

**Alternatively**, and I would consider it a better idea, is to use database triggers to implement your code.

Please, take into account, that I haven't tested the code and it may contain some mistakes, but you have to grasp the idea of how to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What about using *_related methods?

Comment: Can you explain the solution more clearly or even add some code?